# Is there any difference between selected cities select cities?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Since a long time ago, I used to write *selected* instead of *select* because I thought select is just a verb, not adjective.

But recently I came to know it's adjective, because I saw phrases like "select cities/users/phones" etc.

Earlier, for the same phrase, I would write "selected cities/users/phones". I felt it natural and it was like a belief that I thought it *is* the right thing and I never really paid attention to it.

For example, I would write: This game is available for selected users/cities. (My subconscious mind makes me feel both give same feeling and meaning)

Now, I'm sure "select users/cities/etc." make sense and is absolutely right, but also I wonder if I could use "selected" too for the same purpose (in other words, could they be used as synonym phrases)? Or is it totally wrong use?

Comment: 'Select' as an adjective means 'special', but 'selected' used as an adjective means 'chosen'. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would like a bit detailed explanation. Like if I use "selected" instead of select for same purpose, would it change the meaning of sentence? If yes how?

Comment: When you use 'selected' then the presumption is that the choice was made for a particular reason, which is not necessarily 'best', but perhaps even 'worst'. But 'select' is an adjective that does imply 'very good'.

Comment: @WeatherVane grammatically both correct?

Comment: One would not say "the game is available for select users."

Comment: @WeatherVane I just read this online "now available for download, with early access rolling out to select users"

Comment: Well, they used it, but I would not.

Comment: That creates doubts.

Comment: If the download is avalaible to certain users, then they have already been selected by the provider. That does not make them 'select'. It seems to be a marketing ploy to make users feel good.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes it does.